# Why the mail sending successfully but get error in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, email

In the localhost environment, I try to send email to myself, 
and using the following code, I can trully get the mail ,but the 
browser(google chrome) development return message **`Failed to load response data`**.
Why the mail sending successfully but get error in laravel 5 ?

***6/21 :Change the `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp`to `MAIL_DRIVER=mail` and the response can return successfully, but can not get the mail in my mailserver.***

For the security issue ,I using the word `example` to replace the real domain.
And sure, the setting is totally right.
Here is my **`.env`** file :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.example.com
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=system@example.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=123
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

my **`route.php`**

```
Route::post('/ajaxSendEmail', [ 'as' => 'ajaxSendEmail','uses' =>'MyController@ajaxSendEmail' ] );
```

and **token** for html  `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />`

my **`ajax`**

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
     'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
   }
});
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('ajaxSendEmail')}}",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 10000, 
    error: function (error) {
        alert('ajax error');
    }
});
```

my **`Controller`** function

```
  public function ajaxSendEmail()
  {
    $r['returnData'] = Mail::send('email.feedback', ['data'=> 'Hello Mail'], function ($message) {
        $message->from('service@faciwedding.com', 'FACI');
        $message->to('service@faciwedding.com');
        $message->subject('Hello');
    });


    return response()->json($r);
  }
```

my email view **`email.feedback`** 
is very simple.

```
<h1>{{ $data }}</h1>
```

Comment: try `return response()->json(compact('r'));`

Comment: It is still the same.